# Value function and action value function

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In an MDP, for any state `s`, what is the difference between the action value function and value function? I guess they are same because they both are defined w.r.t a policy (say pi). Now if policy is fixed then action on a state is also fixed even though we can have probabilistic transitions.

But not sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value function maps state to the expected return starting from that state. The action value function maps an state-action pair to the expected return obtained after taking that action in that state.

> if policy is fixed then action on a state is also fixed

That's not true, a fixed policy need not be deterministic.